# JHipster gateway index return blank page after some liquibase error

Tags: jhipster

I just started with jHipster with a micro-services and gateway structure.

Here are two cases that after the change, when running ./mvnw, the index will be empty and I cannot do anything anymore (except visiting H2 DB itself)

1. change users.csv  or any other csv files under src/main/resources/config/liquibase
2. run `jhipster import-jdl **.jd` or `jhipster:entity *EntityName*` ** and some error occurs, especially, when trying to add  relationships to an entity itself, it will definitely give send back errors **

Once it when wrong, I have no way to get the system back to work anymore...
Here are what I have tried:

1. run ./mvnw liquibase:diff, add the changelog to master.xml
2. revert the code and all files to the status it worked
3. remove target and node_modules directory
4. run yarn install and ./mvnw

I don't see any error info, not sure if I am doing something wrong, but it is not work...

Comment: liquibase:diff should not be required,as it is on the gateway just drop your database and restart the app. Did you run BOTH mvnw and yarn start on gateway? Did you start the registry ?

Comment: Once it went something wrong, I could got an error look like the following:`2017-07-13 14:10:57.783 ERROR 34215 --- [eway-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20170712082859_added_entity_Company.xml::20170712082859-1::jhipster was: 7:bfb29e78f34ecf69488e06bcc988a2d7 but is now: 7:41f3fff3ecc1927fa42ba632c202c5fa`, this is after I imported an uml file with error and corrected the error, ran the uml successfully.

Comment: Can I know how to correct this error?

Comment: By 'drop' database, will the ./mvnw clean do the thing for me? I thought the liquibase is generated and is under the target...

Comment: Hi @gaël-marziou , thank you, I think yarn start can solve this question! though it is a bit strange that without doing ./mvnw clean, I can just use ./mvnw and visit the port it starts directly, but after that, I need to use yarn start...Thank you very much!

Comment: It's simple, check our docs. in dev, mvn deals with java part and yarn/webpack delas with angular part. The 2 parts are assmbled intagert folder so when you do a mvn clean, you remove both parts. Now in prod profile, that's another story because mvn lacnhes yarn, in dev it's different because we need hot reloading.

Comment: For drop database, you're right the db is under target but only if you use db  in file mode, as I did not know your setup, I used a geenric term: drop.

Comment: Liquibase checksums are a feature, migrations are immutable http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html

Comment: Hi @gaël-marziou , thank you again. Your info is very helpful to me, I will keep study jhipster. I set another question with a more specific problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105987/self-reference-error-by-jhipster , could you please check it if possible?

Comment: @gaël-marziou , sorry, I don't think my question is valid... I somehow made it work, it seems is caused by my bandwidth is too low which led timeout when yarn trying to download something...

Comment: OK then delete your question